# sql query problem

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, compare

i want to compare two date and time with each other and 
i want to select records that "StartTime" is greater than now time and the "StartDate" is greater than now date.

but output is not correct.thanks in advance.
my tabale'records are:

```
StartDate       StartTime
-------------------------------
1389/07/11  11:04
1389/06/23  21:17
1389/06/23  21:32
1389/06/23  22:10
1389/06/26  12:34
1389/06/27  17:29
1389/06/27  18:13
1389/06/27  20:27
1389/06/28  09:41
1389/07/18  10:46
1389/07/05  22:00
1389/07/15  24:00
```

output is:
when the query is :   (1)

```
SELECT        StartDate, StartTime
FROM            Proj
WHERE        (StartDate < '1389/07/15 ') AND (StartTime <= '20:20 ')

StartDate       StartTime   
-------------------------------      
1389/07/11  11:04
1389/06/26  12:34
1389/06/28  09:41
1389/07/18  10:46
```

output is:
when the query is:   (2)

```
SELECT        StartDate, StartTime
FROM            Proj
WHERE        (StartDate > '1389/07/15 ') AND (StartTime >= '20:20 ')

StartDate       StartTime   
------------------------------- 
NULL    NULL
```

the correct output should be:

```
StartDate       StartTime   
------------------------------- 
1389/07/18  10:46
```

i use persian date.

Comment: Can you give the table schema? and you query where time is less than or equal to 20:22.

Comment: The operator should be ">" am I right?

Comment: Maybe stating the obvious but date and time are reserved Sql keywords, what is your error? Have you tried "select * from test where [date]<'2010/10/05' and [time]<='20:20'";

Comment: @ Lee Sy En,@Sascha:i edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it solved:

```
SELECT        StartDate, StartTime
FROM            Proj
WHERE        (StartTime < '20:20 ') AND (StartDate = '1389/07/15') OR
                         (StartDate > '1389/07/15')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just taking what you have above and the description of your problem, the query should be:

```
select * from test where date>'2010/10/05' and time>='20:22'
```

If you post more details about your problem and the schema in which you're working we'll be able to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

*I want to select records that "time" is greater than **now time** and the "date" is greater than **now date**.*

First off to get the current datetime (your now), you can use the SQL function `GETDATE()`.
So if you happen to have a `datetime` column you could just do

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE LogDateTime >= GETDATE()
```

This will return every record in the table Test of which the datetime value inside the LogDateTime column is in the future.

Now, although it's a little bit more complicated, the same can be used when you have split the date and the time into separate columns.

```
SELECT  * FROM Test 
WHERE   CONVERT(datetime, LogDate + ' ' + LogTime) >= GETDATE()
```

If LogDate or LogTime are nullable columns you could use `ISNULL(<columnName>, <defaultvalue>)` to be safe.